# Node Js: Remove string array element from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have a user schema as follows:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 
  skills: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

And a Fetch request to delete a skill as follows:

```
const deleteItem = async (id) => {
    try {
    
      await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/deleteskill`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/JSON", token: accessToken },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userid: userid , skill:id}),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("USER SKILLS:", data.userskills);
        });      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Server

```
const deleteSkill = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.body.userid)
    
    //user.skills.pull(req.body.skill);

    // removeskill = user.skills.filter(function(item) {
    //   return item !== req.body.skill
    // })

    if (user.skills.includes(req.body.skill)) {

      res.status(400).json("Item Still Exists");

    } else {

      res.status(200).json("Item Deleted");
    }

   
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

the array is in the following structure

```
  [
  'skill1', 'java',  'skill5'
]
```

I have tried to remove the user skill from the array in several ways but I still get  `res.status(400).json("Item Still Exists");`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to remove the skill from the Database or in the response array?

Comment: I want to remove an element from the skills array

Comment: then you should provide the whole array output structure in your question.

Comment: you are right. I added the array structure

Comment: I think as per your question you are requesting API to delete a skill from the database, But the skill is not being deleted in the database.

Comment: Yes you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.0/classes/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) method to find a document with the user id and update it in one atomic operation:

```
const deleteSkill = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let message = "Item Deleted";
    let status = 200;
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.userid },
      { $pull: { skills: req.body.skill } },
      { new: true }
    )
    
    if (user && user.skills.includes(req.body.skill)) {
      message = "Item Still Exists";
      status = 400;
    } else if (!user) {
      message = "User Not Found";
      status = 404;
    }
    
    res.status(status).send({ message });
   
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks. this must be exaclty what i need. But i get ``` "error": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'skills')"``` what might be wrong?

Comment: The error is as a result of a user with a given userid not found. To remedy that you need to check if the user exists and return the approriate response, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to remove skills from the database then the following function could help you out.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
 if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var myquery = { userid: userid, skillid: skillid};
  dbo.collection("skills").deleteOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted");
    
  db.close();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a method of removing elements from arrays, if you want to remove the first one you could use array.shift (more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)), but if you want to delete it completely from your database you could always, find it and then [update it](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/crud/update/).

Answer (score 0):

```
User.update({ _id: userid }, { $pull: { "skills": "[skill]" }})
```

Comment: I like that but i get "error": "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'skills')"

Comment: Try User.updateOne(.....)